# Android - setting wallpaper multiple times in a row fails, sets to default

Tags: java, android, service

I have little experience with Android app development. I am trying to build an Android app that changes the wallpaper every couple of seconds. I have the images I want to cycle through stored in an ArrayList of InputStreams and I am sure the values there are correct. I can set the wallpaper once, but when I try to do it multiple times in a row, it sets the wallpaper to the default. It does not throw an exception, though.

When I try to use a loop to change the wallpaper multiple times, sometimes it works 1-3 times before continuing to set it to default. Sometimes it doesn't work once. This is happening in the onHandleIntent method of an intent service.

Here is the loop I use to change the wallpaper:

```
    while(images != null && !(images.isEmpty())){
        //if counter is at end of list, reset to 0
        if(counter == streams.size() - 1) counter = 0;

        //set pic as wallpaper
        try {
            wpm.setStream(streams.get(counter));
            counter++;
        }
        catch (IOException io) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + io.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

To be clear, I know that the while loop's condition variables do not change. I just wrote it that way instead of
using it in an if statement and then nesting a while(true) loop within it. The images I am using are all different sizes.

Comment: This code is incomplete. What is `images`? An String? ArrayList? and why you are not using it in the while? the only variable that is changing in the loop is counter. So I cannot understand what are you doing there. Be more specific.

Comment: Why do you need to know every variable? My question is why successive calls to the set wallpaper method might not work.

Comment: The most important is your JAVA code. So we need that code to help you. Otherwise, it seem that you are asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).